# Can previous Bitlocker recovery keys be used to decrypt old data on disk encrypted with it if current data is encrypt with a new recovery key?

Tags: windows, windows-10, encryption, bitlocker, windows-11

These questions all regard modern windows 10/11 PC’s with SSD’s with Bitlocker device protection (offered with windows 10/11 pro).

1. From what I understand, The master encryption key is randomly generated and encrypted by a randomly generated recovery key, which is the one windows says to save. If Bitlocker was used, and recovery key 1 was used, the Bitlocker was turned off, set to encrypt whole disk, even deleted data, and re-encrypted with a key 2 that was generated and used, will any of the encrypted data From when recovery key 1 was used be able to be recovered if key 1 is available?
2. Alternatively, if a key 3 was generated, but not encrypted if the encryption process window was closed before encryption process started, and the process was started again with a generated recovery key 4, no data was ever touched in relation to key 3?
3. How can Bitlocker protect deleted data if used disk space is changed to whole disk (best if on a used disk to keep any deleted data from easily being recovered) to keep old data from being recovered? Some sort of container file or format lock or something?

Edit: for clarity,

A. is an old recovery key useless if the drive has been re-encrypted since so no need to worry about old recovery keys?

B. How does bitlocker protect delete data exactly if encrypted whole drive is selected, including old deleted data?

Thank you!

Comment: I cant speak with absolute  cettaunty as Im more familiar wth the Linux equivalent (LUKS) but Im pretty sure it works as follows. The disk has a master key which itself can be encrypted with multiple keys.  Any one of those keys xan unlock the main key and decrypt the drive - all keys are equivalent.  There is no difference between deleted and used data as encryption occurs at a partition/disk level - ie below the filesystem.

Comment: To quickly erasecall old data, bitlocker sinply needs to destroy the master key (even if it doesnt know what it is, it just needs to know where it is)

Comment: To my knowledge, the recovery key isn't used to encrypt or decrypt the data.  It can be used to suspend BitLocker protection which in turn writes the actual key (used for the encryption) to the disk.  Additionally, if you disable BitLocker protection, all data will have to be written to the disk again unencrypted. I am not sure what your rest of your question is asking, you are not going to have a BItLocker key, if BitLocker protection is not enabled.  BitLocker does not used containers. **You can either encrypt the entire disk or just the used space.** Options on a system volume are differnt.

Comment: How can it encrypt the entire disk including used space if it rewrites existing data in an encrypted form?

Comment: And the other part of my question was meaning that if you select encrypt drive options, it shows you the recovery key to save before you click encrypt disk, but before you encrypt it, if you close out, go back, and go through the option again, it will generate a new recovery key without encrypting. So that key can’t be used to decrypt anything, or any other old recovery key, since that is not the one encrypting the master key anymore?

Comment: Why don't you simply look at the active recovery keys yourself? `manage-bde -protectors C: -get` prints all protectors which includes all active (working) recovery keys.

Comment: So recovery keys that are no longer active can’t be used for anything or decrypt anything?

Answer (score 1):

No, they cannot.

The recovery key is not a decryption key. It is more like a strong password that unlocks the decryption key.

Knowing an old recovery key does not give you any access to data, current or old.

Answer (score -3):

I have no idea how MS handles encryption.

Good practice would be to random-write the entire partition/drive to muddle the physical location/amount of  data.

"Delete" properly means "overwrite with random data" not "change symlink to recycle bin" or whatever crap windows does.
HOWEVER - if the "recycle bin" was on the same encrypted partition, it should be just as encrypted as before.
It strikes me as unlikely that even windows would be so retarded as to send data from an encrypted partition to a clear one.

The standard would be that "clear" data encrypted with any key, can only be accessed with that key, regardless of if it has been encrypted/decrypted with alternate keys in the past.
You can generate as many keys as you like, if nothing is "locked" with them, they're irrelevant. (Again, no idea how MS implements this.)

"Container file or format lock"??

"Protect deleted data" It's encrypted.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all, and is not really accurate even in a few of the statements it makes -  eg a single key is NOT a best practice - Neither LUKS nor Bitlocker do that... When talking about block device encryption, delete means destroy the master key. (Bitlocker, LUKS, SSD hardware encryption, Veracrypt... all are the same in this regard)

Comment: I see also you have not provided an answer to the OP? If we want to nitpick, windows is not best practice, and I don't think you'll find me advocating symetrical encryption anywhere. Delete, at a file level, not a key/partition level, means exactly what I said above. Unless you've interpreted the OP differently.

Comment: I did not provide an answer because I do not know enough about the intricacies of Bitlocker.  I did provide substantial comments which are very close to an answer - which (once you have enough reputation to do it) is the appropriate way to communicate relevant information which does not meet the bar of being an answer.

Comment: @mitts - Personally the only reason I have not submitted an answer is due to the fact I am extremely confused about what the author is actually asking. I would agree that this answer fails to answer the author's question, and you admit, your knowledge is extremely lacking on the specifics of BitLocker.